# Dynamic paint effect disappears after first frame in rendered animation (waves lapping on a beach)

Tags: rendering, modifiers, ocean-simulation, dynamic-paint

I'm using the beach (modified plain w/ textures applied) as the canvas and another plain with an *Ocean* modifier as the brush. All is visible and seems to work in *Solid View* when scrubbing the *Time Simulator* of the *Ocean* modifier.

And, I can successfully render a single image (*Dynamic Paint* shows up) at any random time.

[image]

The problem is with key framing the *Time Simulator* on the *Ocean* modifier. Although the *Dynamic Paint* animation seems to work in *Solid View*, it disappears after the first frame upon rendering the animation.

[image]

I'm stumped and have no idea how to fix this. It leaves me wondering if I've missed something fundamental.
I'd greatly appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My bad. Here's the Blend file...  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1885" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1885/)